# Forward my public ip address to my xampp webserver

Tags: router, modem, webserver, xampp

I am trying to forward my public ip address with port 80 to a xampp webserver.

I have an ADSL modem and a wireless media router.

I have done the following:

1. Reserved a DHCP address inside the wireless router (using the mac address hosting the webserver) so that my ip address never changed when I connect to the wireless router.
2. Setup a Virtual Server port forwarding to TCP/UDP port 80 inside the wireless router so that it forwards to my http server.

Whats happening:

When I type my public ip address into my web browser it goes to my ADSL modem and not my webserver or my wireless router. Unfortunately the modem is not wireless so we got a wireless router installed.  In the DHCP server settings of the modem, it has DHCP activated with a range from 10.1.1.2 to 10.1.1.254. I do not know what those addresses are. I did try to put in my own actual Internal IP Address but I wasn't allowed as ip address wasn't in the range of 10.1.1.2 to 10.1.1.254.

So internet still works, my router address works.

- Wireless Router: DIR-855
- ADSL Modem: DSL-502T

Anyone knows what I should do?

Comment: Are you inside your network and trying to access your webserver using the public address?  This is called hairpinning and is unlikely to work with a domestic router.  Have you tried from outside the network?

Comment: yes, I am trying to access the webserver in a webbrowser from one of my lan reserved ip addresses by typing in the public ip address. No I haven't tried to access it from outside the network as yet.

Answer (score 1):

I realised that I am supposed to have the modem bridged to the wireless router. I selected *bridged* for the modem and then PPOE for the router, then entered in the PPoE details from the modem into the wireless router and it worked fine.

Now when I type in the public IP address into the router from my PC, it launches my website.

Solved that problem.